# Dataflow worker subnetwork is not accessible to Dataflow Service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

When i run a job on Dataflow, i get an error.

```
INFO: 2018-05-13T04:43:38.642Z: Checking required Cloud APIs are enabled.
May 13, 2018 11:44:09 AM org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.MonitoringUtil$LoggingHandler process
INFO: 2018-05-13T04:43:38.927Z: Checking permissions granted to controller Service Account.
May 13, 2018 11:44:09 AM org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.MonitoringUtil$LoggingHandler process
SEVERE: 2018-05-13T04:43:51.378Z: Workflow failed. Causes: Subnetwork regions/asia-southeast1/subnetworks/SUBNETWORK is not accessible to Dataflow Service account
May 13, 2018 11:44:09 AM org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.MonitoringUtil$LoggingHandler process
INFO: 2018-05-13T04:43:53.038Z: Cleaning up.
```

My command line

```
mvn compile -X exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.to.class \
"-Dexec.args=--runner=DataflowRunner \
...
--network=NETWORKNAME \
--subnetwork=regions/asia-southeast1/subnetworks/SUBNETWORK \
--zone=asia-east1-a \
--region=asia-east1 \
" -Pdataflow-runner
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subnetwork is in the `asia-southeast1` region whereas the workers are in `asia-east1`. You can use a subnetwork in `asia-east1` or provision the VMs in one of the `asia-southeast1` zones instead but both will need to match. For the latter approach, take into account that `asia-southeast1`is not a [supported regional endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/regional-endpoints) as of now so you can't specify it with the `--region` flag for control and metadata purposes (you can however spin up workers with the `--zone` flag).